# Nothing inside my $(document).ready works

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, pug

I have been looking around all day and cannot figure out why none of the code inside my `$(document).ready` wrapper works.

layout.jade

```
!!!5
html
    head
        title #{title}
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.js')
        script.
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert("working");
                $("#message").html("message set through jquery");
            });
    body
        header
            h1 Sample message here
        .container
            .main-content
                block content
            .sidebar
                block sidebar
        footer
            block foot
```

landing.jade

```
extends layout
block content
    p#message Landing page
    #info Info area
block foot
    a(href="https://localhost:8888/logout", title="logout") Logout
```

controller:

```
exports.landing = function(req, res) {
    res.render('landing', {title: 'My Title'});
}
```

rendered html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Dashboard</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message").html("message set through jquery");
});
alert("working");</script></head><body><header><h1>Sample Web App</h1></header><div class="container"><div class="main-content"><p id="message">Landing page</p><div id="info">Info area</div></div><div class="sidebar"></div></div><footer><a href="https://localhost:8888/logout" title="logout">Logout</a></footer></body></html>
```

console error:
I just checked the console on the page, not where I'm running my Express web server, and found an error:

```
Uncaught reference error: $ is not defined
```

https server issue:

The primary problem was two fold: 1) I was using the wrong url as recognized by @Joe. 2) Since my web server was created in Express as https, not http, it was refusing to use the url with the non-secure http address listed in @Joe's answer. Instead, I needed to modify it to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js so that my https web server would use it, as recommended by @Frédéric Hamidi.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: does anything outside of it work?

Comment: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.js" is throwing a 404 - you probably meant to use this: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ?

Comment: The rendered html looks like it should work, everything else outside of this piece works. I can call external js functions just fine, but anything inside the wrapper for jquery fails, even the alert doesn't work. I changed the src destination to that url @Joe but still no luck.

Comment: may we please see a a paste bin of the html output? what is the console saying? thnx

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: @gjw80, can you reproduce this problem on more than one browser?

Comment: Yes, same problem exists in chrome and IE

Comment: @gjw80, okay, I'm grasping at straws here, but does a call to `alert()` outside of `ready()` but in the same `<script>` element succeed? If it doesn't, look for stray HTML comments around the `<script>` element in the page source.

Comment: The call to `alert()` outside `ready` but inside `script.` does not work.

Comment: How about ALL of the rendered HTML?

Comment: @JAL, *ALL* can be *huge*, but some context around the script would indeed be helpful. gjw80, my best bet is on stray HTML comments, then. Loading the rendered page source in a syntax-highlighting editor would be a quick way to check.

Comment: I don't see why all the HTML would or could be huge for the jade document specified in the example. We just need to see the entire head section at least.

Comment: @JAL, we don't see `block sidebar`, but you're right the markup up to the `<body>` element would be enough, yes.

Comment: What's an easy way to copy all of the rendered html out of the page?

Comment: @gjw80, err... *View Page Source* in the context menu? How did you post part of the rendered HTML if you don't know how to copy the rendered HTML in the first place?

Comment: I copied it from inspect element.

Comment: Ah, that's not quite the same thing. The inspection feature renders the DOM as it currently is, not as how it was when the page was originally loaded.

Comment: I added it up top, it's not formatted though.

Comment: I did find an error in the console, I didn't realize there was a console directly on the page. I was looking at the console in my IDE for my web server created by Express.

Comment: @gjw80, we're making progress :) Please paste `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` directly in the address bar of your browser and tell us what happens.

Comment: When I press enter it loads a giant unformatted file which appears to be an API

Comment: Then the markup in your question should work because `$` should be defined. With any luck, loading the jQuery script directly refreshed your local copy and things will work from now on. Otherwise I'm at a loss to explain what's going on :|

Comment: If I am running all of this on an https server (not http) created by Express would that make a difference?

Comment: Unless your browser cannot access `http://ajax.googleapis.com/`, no. And if it did not, you would not have seen the script.

Comment: @gjw80, on second thought, try using `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` as the jQuery script's source URL. Your browsers *might* be configured to silently refuse to load HTTP resources when the main document is served through HTTPS.

Comment: That's it, I needed to add https to the url. It now works. Thank you! Please add your response as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @gjw80, thanks, done. For a while I lost hope to find the root cause of your problem, fortunately there is no magic involved in programming :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your development environment appears to be quite peculiar :)

The jQuery script fails to load because it is served through HTTP, the main document is served through HTTPS, and both your browsers have been configured to silently drop HTTP requests made from a document served through HTTPS.

Fortunately, the Google CDN supports both HTTP and HTTPS, so you only have to switch protocols in the script source URL:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, that was you arguing, ok then, sorry=)

Comment: @Alder, heh :) Actually, protocol is key here, so your answer would not work either because it also uses HTTP instead of HTTPS to fetch the script. dc2 (through Joe)'s answer, on the other hand, would probably work because it does not specify the protocol (plain `//ajax.googleapis.com/`) and in that case it will default to the protocol used by the main document IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

See Joe's comment:

> "code.jquery.com/jquery-1.js"; is throwing a 404 - you probably meant
>   to use this:
>   "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ? –  Joe
>   38 mins ago

This is probably your answer. +1 to Joe.

Comment: @gjw80, It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/7V8jy/ I simple past your "rendered html"

Answer (score 1):

Just change link as they said. I changed on `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`